# How to center column indicies over a right aligned column with blockarray

Tags: equations, blkarray

I am using `blockarray` and `block`s from the [blkarray package](https://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray) to create a row/column indexed matrix consisting of 0’s, 1’s and -1’s. How can I get the indexes centered over the right aligned columns? This is what I would like to get:

[image]

Here is a MWE of what I've tried so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray,bigstrut}
\newcommand\topstrut[1][1.2ex]{\setlength\bigstrutjot{#1}{\bigstrut[t]}}
\newcommand\botstrut[1][0.9ex]{\setlength\bigstrutjot{#1}{\bigstrut[b]}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
A_{H}=\begin{blockarray}{*{9}{c}c}
    \begin{block}{*{9}{c}c}
        \{a,b\} & \{b,c\} & \{c,d\} & (a,b) & (b,a) & (c,b)  & (d,b)  & (e,f)  & (f,e) \\[-0.6ex]
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{(*{9}{r})c}
        1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a \topstrut \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & b \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & d \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & e \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & f \botstrut \\
    \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

and it produces:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's *much* easier with `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
A_{H}=
\begin{pNiceArray}{*{9}{S[table-format=-1.0]}}[first-row,last-col,code-for-last-col=\enspace]
  {\{a,b\}} &
  {\{b,c\}} &
  {\{c,d\}} &
  {(a,b)} &
  {(b,a)} &
  {(c,b)} &
  {(d,b)} &
  {(e,f)} &
  {(f,e)} &
\\
  1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & b \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & d \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & e \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & f \\
\end{pNiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With dirty trick -- move  `r` columnfor `\quad`` space to left:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray,bigstrut}
\newcommand\topstrut[1][1.2ex]{\setlength\bigstrutjot{#1}{\bigstrut[t]}}
\newcommand\botstrut[1][0.9ex]{\setlength\bigstrutjot{#1}{\bigstrut[b]}}

\begin{document}
    \[
A_{H}=\begin{blockarray}{*{9}{c}c}
    \begin{block}{*{9}{c}c}
        \{a,b\} & \{b,c\} & \{c,d\} & (a,b) & (b,a) & (c,b)  & (d,b)  & (e,f)  & (f,e) \\[-0.6ex]
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{(*{9}{r<{\quad}})c}   % <---
        1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a \topstrut \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & b \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & d \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & e \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & f \botstrut \\
    \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can produce it without [`blkarray`](//ctan.org/pkg/blkarray) and using [`siunitx`](//ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)'s `S`-column for alignment around the negative numbers:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\[
  A_H =
    % Left bracket
    \left( \begin{array}{ @{} l @{} } \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \end{array} \right.
    \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
    % Center matrix and column indices
    \raisebox{.5\baselineskip}{$\begin{array}{ @{} *{3}{c} *{6}{ S[table-format = -1] } @{} }
      {\{a, b\}} & {\{b, c\}} & {\{c, d\}} & {(a, b)} & {(b, a)} & {(c, d)} & {(d, b)} & {(e, f)} & {(f, e)} \\
      1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
    \end{array}$}
  % Right bracket and row indices
  \left) \begin{array}{ c @{} } a \\ b \\ c \\ d \\ e \\ f \end{array} \right.
\]

\end{document}
```